# Proof check $(\log\log n) /(\log n) $ approaches zero

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, logarithms

Proof : If $|a| < 1$ then $(na^n)$ is a null sequence therefore if $b>1$ then ${n\over (b)^n}$ is a null sequence.There is always an $m$ such that for every  $n > m$ $${n\over (b)^n} <\epsilon' = {\epsilon\over b}$$ Now if g is the characteristic of $\log\log n$ then $g\le \log\log n\lt g+1$. Therefore $${\log\log n\over \log n} < {g+1\over (b)^g}= b{g+1\over (b)^ {g+1}} $$ So if we choose $n>b^{b^m}$ we would have $g+1 > m$ and so  $|{\log\log n\over \log n}| < \epsilon$. 
(Side note: for the logarithm the base b > 1 that is being used in here and the theorem).

Comment: The beginning of the first sentence makes no sense. Was it perhaps meant to read $na^n$?

Comment: Yes it was my bad.

Comment: If you know that $\frac{t}{e^t}\to 0$ when $t\to \infty$ then just set $t_n=\log\log n\to\infty$.

Comment: I am aware of that as well but I would like to know if this proof is valid or not.

Comment: What is characteristic??

Comment: There is mantissa and characteristic. For example the number 4.1324; 4 is a characteristic and the mantissas are the numbers after the decimal point. For a better explanation google it.

Comment: Your proof is valid but you have not mentioned the fact that $b > 1$ is the base of the logarithm used here. If by $\log n$ you mean the natural logarithm of $n$ then it is better to write $e$ instead of $b$. BTW very good proof based on sequences namely the fact that $na^{n} \to 0$ for $|a| < 1$. Most other proofs use real variable theory that $(\log x)^{a}/x^{b} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ for positive $a, b$.

Comment: Yes that is why I was in search of a way to use the sequences that actually are null sequences. And I have mentioned that b>1 is being used in the proof and the theorem.Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 2):

**An other way :**

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\ln(\ln(n))}{\ln n}\underset{m=\ln n}{=}\lim_{m\to\infty }\frac{\ln m}{m}\underset{\text{(Hospital)}}{=}\lim_{m\to\infty }\frac{1}{m}$$

Then if $N=\lfloor\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rfloor+1$, you have that
$$\left|\frac{\ln(\ln(n))}{\ln(n)}\right|<\varepsilon$$
if $n\geq N$ what prove the claim.